# How to mock returned object from inner method on some other class in java

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I read at least 20 posts but still couldn't find the answer. So, posting this question. May be it is answered in some other post, which I couldn't find.

```
    class OuterService {
        InnerService innerService;
        @Autowired
        public void setInnerService(InnerService innerService){
            this.innerService = innerService;
        }
        public void method() {
            List<C> listOfC = new ArrayList<C>(); 
            C c =  new C();
            c.setUserProfiles(someObject);

            c = innerService.invokeMethod(String str1,Map map, 
            String str2, Object obj1, String str3, String str4, 
            C c, String str5); 


            c.setCreatedDate(some String value);  // Here c comes null while executing jUnits.
            listOfC.add(c);
        }
    }
```

Here is my Test class:

```
   import org.junit.Before;


    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Matchers;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import org.mockito.Mockito;
    import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
    import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
    import com.pogo.service.DeviceRegistrationService;

    @SuppressFBWarnings("RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED_NO_SIDE_EFFECT")
    @SpringBootTest
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    class ClassOuterServiceTest {

        @InjectMocks
        OuterService outerService;
        @Mock
        InnerService innerService;
        @Mock C c;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            outerService.setInnerService(innerService);
        }

        @Test
        public void methodTest() {
        when(innerService.invokeMethod(Mockito.anyString(), 
        Mockito.any(Map.class), Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(), 
            Mockito.any(PersonSessionToken.class), Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), 
            Mockito.any(RequestHeader.class),Mockito.any(C.class), 
            Mockito.anyString() )).thenReturn(c);


            doNothing().when(c).invokeCMethod();
            outerService.method();
        }
    }
```

But I get null inside object c in OuterService.java. Also if I use Matchers.any() or Matchers.anyString() in invokeMethod() then , it shows Matchers exception.

What is the appropriate solution?

Comment: @MadhuBhat: I have injected InnerService using setter injection. It is able to call invokeMethod(). It is not the problem.  Problem is, object returned by innerService.invokeMethod() is returning null  even when I use when().thenreturn(c);

Comment: @Ruchi When you add a null check in your `setInnerService()` methods like `this.innerService = Objects.requireNotNull(innerService);`, do you get an exception?

Comment: ARe you using any annotations on `ClassOuterServiceTest`? something like `@RunWith RUNNER`

Comment: try `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(ClassOuterServiceTest.class);` instead of `this`

Comment: what param1 and param2 are when you are setting to mock?

Comment: @OhadY: param1 and param2 are strings.

Comment: @Progman: I have checked by placing System.out.println(); that innerService is not null.

Comment: @ArunGowda: I'm using @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Comment: @Ruchi Please [edit] your question to include the full source code of the `OuterService` class, `InnerService` class, the full `ClassOuterServiceTest` test case and the complete error message you get, including the full stack trace.

Comment: @Ruchi try adding `@Test` on your test method.

Comment: Change `param1` and `param2` to `Mockito.anyString()` in test method

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the object for `OuterService` use `@InjectMocks` annotation and when you use method stubbing use mock objects only. In your program you are creating object for `c`. Instead of creating object just use `@Mock` annotation.

When you using `Mockito.any()` mention the class inside parenthesis. `Mockito.any(C.class)` like this.

> Don't use `PowerMockRunner` unless you are testing static or final classes.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassOuterServiceTestC {

    @Mock
    public InnerService innerService;
    @InjectMocks
    public OuterService outerService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void methodTest() {

        C obj = mock(C.class);
        when(innerService.invokeMethod(anyString(), anyMap(), anyString(), any(), anyString(), anyString(), any(TestC.class), anyString()))
                .thenReturn(obj);
        doNothing().when(obj).setUserProfiles(any(Object.class));
        doNothing().when(obj).setCreatedDate(anyString());

        outerService.method();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, As your solution using anyString(), anyString() work till half way. that's why putting the entire scenario which I'm using. I have edited my question.   Now, when I use anyString() for String and any() for Object, I get Matchers Exception. And when I pass new C() object  instead of Matchers.any() for "C c" , then I receive NUllpointerException.     I also tried Matchers.eq(passing new C object), but still I get NullPointerException, where c is actually used to call some method inside invokeMethod().

Comment: It is throwing NullPointerException from inside invokeMethod() at very first line , where c.some() method is getting called.

Comment: @Ruchi are you doing unit test are integration test?

Comment: I'm just doing Unit test. But why it is going inside invokeMethod() call?

Comment: @Ruchi can you post the test class exaclty without modyfing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213011/discussion-between-komatiraju032-and-ruchi).